# Connect two Tornado applications

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a remote sensor which is connected to my Tornado server by a long living websocket session:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  def open(self):
    puts('New connection was opened.')
    self.write_message('Connection open.')

  def on_message(self, message):
    print 'Incoming message:', message
    self.write_message(message)

  def on_close(self):
    print 'Connection was closed...'

sensor_application = Application([  (r'/ws', WSHandler)])
```

I then have another application for a web based gui:

```
class HelloHandler(RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.render('index.html')

client_application = Application([ (r'/', HelloHandler)])
```

and both of these applications are run on different ports.

```
  ws_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(sensor_application)
  ws_server.listen(8889)

  http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(client_application)
  http_server.listen(8888)

  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Say my sensor measures temperature. How would I implement a page in HelloHandler which could call a websocket method in WSHandler and show the temperature to the web based client.

Comment: why are you trying to implement two different application? only one application can solve your problem.

Comment: Because I am connecting three computers, the client, the server and the sensor. I need an extra connection between the server and sensor and I don't know how to solve it using only one application - if you could explain how please do!

Comment: You can create one application with a list of handlers: `Application([(r'/', HelloHandler), (r'/ws', WSHandler)])`. But that doesn't solve your real problem, since the question then becomes how to connect two handlers. Being in the same application doesn't really make this any easier, it just saves you a port number. Two handlers can communicate by global variables if you only run a single process; otherwise they'll need to use some sort of database or message queue.